# How to let my own program open on a given workspace?

Tags: window-manager, workspaces

I maintain a Linux program run on various distributions. Some customers complain that it always opens on a wrong workspace (= virtual desktop). They'd prefer it to start on the workspace where it was recently closed.

We have an installer and create a desktop shortcut, which gets used to open our program. Somewhere, I read that the shortcut saves this information and that the window manager uses it to store the window position and workspace, but that seems to be constrained to few distributions, right?

*What can I do to to make our program open on a specified workspace?* A tool like `kstart` or `wmctrl` doesn't seem to be generally available.

Can I find out the current workspace of a my program's main window? I can [find out the current workspace](https://askubuntu.com/q/17484/10802) when the window is closing, but this needn't be the same.

Comment: I doubt that there is a general solution. I assume you have to detect the respective desktop environment and use the appropriate tool then.

Comment: @HaukeLaging This could be acceptable, if I could cover the majority of system without dozens of them. However, I've just determined that for OpenSuse-Leap-42, `kstart` works with xterm but not with our program (and there's no `vmctrl` and `yast` doesn't know it).

Comment: There is also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie